# Why my lambda is working only when i give a callback with some message?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am trying to run a small snippet of lambda code where i am pushing data to S3 using firehose. Here is my snippet

```
const AWS = require( 'aws-sdk' );
var FIREhose = new AWS.Firehose();
exports.handler = async (event,context,callback) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode:200,
        Name:event.Name,
        Value:event.Value
    };
const params = {
  DeliveryStreamName: 'kinesis-firehose', 
  Record: { Data: new Buffer(JSON.stringify(response)) }
};

FIREhose.putRecord(params, (err, data) => {
if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);
});
};
```

Here are my events

```
{
  "Name": "Mike",
  "Value": "66"
}
```

When i run this lambda all i am getting response as `null` . Since i am not passing any callback lambda will default run the implicit callback and returns null. I see that no data is pushed to S3 bucket.
But when i add `callback(null,"success")` line at the end like this

```
FIREhose.putRecord(params, (err, data) => {
if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);
});
callback(null,"success")
};
```

I see the data is pushed to S3. Why is that ?
Does `async` functions always need a callback with some text appended to it ?
Any help is appreciated ?
Thanks

Comment: Don't you need to return a promise?

Comment: You means `async` always needs a callback(i.e.promise) ?

Comment: I don't think that's what I mean, but reading the docs, I'm no longer certain exactly what's happening here... but I suspect that calling the callback is actually fixing the issue by accident -- a coincidence of timing.  An implicit return from an async function that doesn't use `await` seems unlikely to do the right thing consistently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you're mixing your node.js lambda patterns.

*Either* you use an asynchronous function and return or throw:

```
exports.handler = async (event,context,callback) => {
  // code goes here.

  await FIREhose.putRecord(params).promise();
  return null; // or whatever result.
};
```

*Or* you use the callback approach:

```
exports.handler = (event,context,callback) => {
  // code goes here.

  FIREhose.putRecord(params)
    .promise();
    .then((data) => {
      // do stuff with data.
      // n.b. you could have used the cb instead of a promise here too.
      callback(null, null); // or whatever result.
    });
};
```

(There's a third way using `context.` but that's a *very* legacy way).

This is all due to how lambda works and detects when there's been a response.

In your first example (no callback), lambda is expecting your handler to return a promise that it has to wait to resolve/reject, which, in turn, will be the response. However, you're not returning a promise (`undefined`) and so there's nothing to wait for and it immediately returns- quite probably before the putRecord call has completed.

When you used `callback` though, you explicitly told lambda that you're using the "old" way. And the interesting thing about the `callback` approach is that it *waits* for node's event loop to complete (by default). Which means that `.putRecord` will probably complete.